# surf plot of f(x,y). With gridlines, but more sparse than default

Tags: matlab

surf(x,y,z) where z is oscillatory.  Therefore x,y are 100x100.  I want the gridlines (don't want to use flat or interp options).  However, too many gridlines don't look good.  Looking for a way to reduce gridlines by 50% or 75% etc. in both x and y coord.

Comment: You might want to consider changing the edge transparency. For instance, `surf(x,y,z,'EdgeAlpha',0.5)`. You could also change the grid color to gray instead of black. You could also change the edge style.

Comment: You could also change the edge width. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like matlab provides an easy way to manually set the gridline spacing. If you really want to, I suspect that you could do so by using the `AlphaData` parameter.

Comment: By the way, this strikes me as a question that's more appropriate for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: OK, in the future then.  But changing alpha works well.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the comments, here's a quick demonstration of what's going on.

[image]

### Code:

```
f = @(x,y) exp(-x.^2 - y.^2);
L = 2;
dx = .01;

dy = dx;
x = -L:dx:L;
y = x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = f(X,Y);

tiledlayout(2,2);
nexttile
surf(X,Y,Z);
title('Default')

nexttile
surf(X,Y,Z,'EdgeAlpha',0.2)
title('EdgeAlpha = 0.2')

nexttile
surf(X,Y,Z,'LineStyle',':')
title('Line Style = :')

nexttile
surf(X,Y,Z,'LineStyle','-.')
title('Line Style = -.')
```